# How to white-out outside of an curve with OpenCV Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on a project, where I need to have a fixed radius curve with a thickness as an region of interest, and white-out anything else on the in the image(without drawing the curve into the image).

The curve is like this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTxxW.png)

I have tried masking, but I couldn't do it without drawing the curve.

Comment: So, a circle? You want to keep what is on the circle with a thickness tolerance?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, starting with this image.
[image]

If I want a mask for a circle of center 1200,600, radius 700 with a thickness of
500, I compute exactly that

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread('cat.jpg')

x0,y0,r,th=1200,600,700,250
H,W,NC=img.shape
x=np.arange(W)[None,:]
y=np.arange(H)[:,None]
d=np.sqrt((x-x0)**2 + (y-y0)**2)
mask=(d>r-th) & (d<r+th)
```

`mask` is a 2D-array of the same shape of the image, of booleans, `True` in the circle, `False` elsewhere.
Note that `x` and `y` are 1D-arrays, extended in phony 2D-array. `x` with only 1 row and W columns. `y` with `H` rows and 1 column.

Broadcasting of any operations combining `x` and `y` lead to a result that is 2D, `H` rows and `W` columns. Most similar code on internet (including on SO) use `meshgrid` for such cases. But I think that is useless waste of memory. Broadcasting does the job as fast with less memory. 90% of the `meshgrid` you see in examples should be replaced by broadcasting, like in this code.

I can use this mask to draw in red, as you did (just to validate its shape)

```py
res=img.copy()
res[mask,2]=255
```

[image]

Or I can use it to white out the rest

```py
res=img.copy()
res[~mask]=(255,255,255)
```

[image]